# Children elements fill space to match width of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I have 2 divs like so that are siblings of variable width because the text or buttons within are in vw units, how can I get the child buttons to fill the space equally to match the width of the first sibling div?

```
<div id="a"><p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p></div>
<div id="b"><button>quick</button><button>fox jumps</button><button>dog</button></div>
```

I tried doing this by setting each div to `width:max-content;` and then using jquery to take the difference of `$('#a').width()-$('#b').width()` and divide it by 6, giving each 1/6th piece to the left and right padding of each button. However that didn't seem to work.

I would prefer to maintain the above HTML structure, but I assume I could but the paragraph and buttons in one div and set the paragraph to 100% and each button to 33.33333% width. But is there another way?

I thought flexbox might with flex-grow, but I shouldn't have to use flexbox for something like this, should I?

What is the proper and robust way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: is this what you're going for? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWVYYX

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yes, exactly that. But while that solves my problem, is there another (either more supported or more efficient) way to achieve this style? Either way, please put that as the answer in case I need to check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery to make the elements' width match, then set the buttons to `flex-grow: 1` or use the shorthand equivalent.

```js
$('#b').width($('#a').width());
```

```css
div {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}

#b {
  display: flex;
}
button {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">
  <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
</div>
<div id="b"><button>quick</button><button>fox jumps</button><button>dog</button></div>
```

Or if the first line is always going to be longer than the second line, You can wrap  them both in an element and either `float` it or set it to `display: inline-block` or `position: absolute` so that it isn't 100% width, then make `#b` a flex parent and set the `button`s to `flex-grow: 1` or use the shorthand.

```css
div {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}

section {
  display: inline-block;
}

#b {
  display: flex;
}
button {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="a">
    <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
  </div>
  <div id="b"><button>quick</button><button>fox jumps</button><button>dog</button></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with is wrap it all in a floated div.

```css
button {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.test {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<div id="a"><p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p></div>
<div id="b"><button>quick</button><button>fox jumps</button><button>dog</button></div>
</div>
```